# Sending a calculated amount to PayPal

Tags: javascript, paypal

This is probably a beginners question but that's where I am right now.

I've managed to create a price calculation sheet using javascript, which takes user entered options from a form, calculates the price total and displays it all fine (using a var named "finalTotalPrice")

Now I want to send it to PayPal, into my Website Payments Standard facility. (I've chosen the Customised Shopping Cart), but can't seem to make it happen.

How do I send the calculated total to PayPal?

The paypal card script works fine when a number is inserted into the amount_1 value field but not when I try using the variable.

I'd love some help if someone has a moment.

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to accept/process a payment based on a calculation done client-side? Doesn't that mean somebody playing with some simple client dev/debugging tools could modify your script and order expensive things with their own substituted total amount of $0.01?

Comment: Thanks nnnnnn. I understand the risk however in my case I'm selling a physical tour and customers need to get to Australia to participate. The products are high value but low volume and we check each and every one before confirming so I believe the practical risk of fraudulent booking is very low.

Answer (score 1):

I have issues with JavaScript rounding numbers badly (because they are floats, even if they are integer values). I highly recommend you use something like PHP to handle the final price stuff. So maybe have a form that's all JavaScript-powered, then PHP processes it (as an integer amount of cents, which only gets divided by 100 right at the end) and `echo`s out the result.

When dealing with money, it is very important to be precise.

This doesn't exactly answer your question, but it does give important advice. But also, since you would be `echo`ing out the resulting PayPal form variables, your HTML has the number directly in the field and it'll work nicely.

Comment: OK Kolink, that sounds promising.  I'll try the dividng by 100 trick.  I did see sme code examples a few days ago that did this.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

After a lot of playing around I've got it working.  The answer appears to be two-fold,

1. a spelling correction to the document.getElementById declaration, and
2. formatting the price total as a number with 2 decimal places.

Thanks guys for your pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Update the paypal hidden variable everytime you change finalTotalPrice or when(just before) you submit the form.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, the finaltotalPrice is already updated each time a change is made by the user.